# Computing similarity score for lists

Tags: r, list, similarity

I have two dataset: a dataset A containing 250000 lists, and a dataset B containing 3000000 lists.
For each of the list in the dataset A, I want to find the most similar list in the dataset B.

The lists have different length and contain strings of the same length.

I realized that a way to go can be to calculate the levenhstein distance between the items in the list but I don't know how to evaluate the various items.

Here there is an example of one list from dataset A

```
listA1 <- list("A61M  16", "A61M2207", "B29C  33", "B29C  45")
```

And here there is a sample of 10 observations in dataset B

```
listB <- list('1' = list("H01Q  19"), '2' = list("A61C   7"), '3' = list("A61C   7"), 
              '4' = list("A24B  13","A24D   1","A24F  15","B65D  85"), '5' = list("A47J  27","A47J  37"),
              '6' = list("C07D 311"), '7' = list("B24B   1","B24B  19","B24B  21","B24B  33"),
              '8' = list("C08J   5","C08J2327","D01D   5","D01F   8","Y10T 428"), '9' =list("B42F  13"),
              '10' = list("A61C   1","E03B   7","E03B   9"))
```